# Create a valid google visualization data array from a json response in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below JSON response

```
[
    {line:"BAH", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"DOM", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"GLW", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"KID", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"KLO", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"KUA", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"KZM", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"LAL", data:{Feb:31, Mar:59, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MAN", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MID", data:{Feb:0}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MIK", data:{Mar:0, Feb:31}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"MKA", data:{Apr:90}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MOR", data:{Mar:59, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MUP", data:{Mar:28}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"NGR", data:{Feb:31, Mar:59, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"NUR", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"RUV", data:{Feb:31, Mar:59, Jun:151}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"TBR", data:{Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"URM", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"UVZ", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"WMI", data:{Jan:0}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}
]
```

I would like to create a google data array that can be display on google charts with below format

```
['MONTH',,'BAH','DOM','GLW','KID','KLO','KUA','KZM','LAL','MAN','MID','MIK','MKA','MOR','MUP','NGR','NUR','RUV','TBR','URM','UVZ','WM'],
['JAN', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['FEB', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['MAR', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['APR', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['MAY', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['JUN', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['JULY',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['AUG', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['SEP', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['OCT', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['NOV', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
['DEC', 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I would wish to replace the 0 with the actual values read from the JSON data. and form a valid google chart array. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some of what you've tried first?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you want to take all the values of `line` and form an array? Where will the names of months and values `0` come from?

Comment: I have found a solution. Highcharts can consume my JSON. see below code

Answer (score 0):

I Found a better solution Highharts.

```
 series_results = [
    {line:"BAH", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"DOM", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"GLW", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"KID", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"KLO", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"KUA", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"KZM", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"LAL", data:{Feb:31, Mar:59, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MAN", data:{Mar:43.5, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MID", data:{Feb:0}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MIK", data:{Mar:0, Feb:31}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"MKA", data:{Apr:90}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MOR", data:{Mar:59, Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"MUP", data:{Mar:28}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"NGR", data:{Feb:31, Mar:59, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"NUR", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}, 
    {line:"RUV", data:{Feb:31, Mar:59, Jun:151}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"TBR", data:{Apr:90, May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"URM", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"UVZ", data:{May:120}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"},
    {line:"WMI", data:{Jan:0}, source:"TANZANIA RAILWAYS"}
]

    var data_series = JSON.parse(series_results) ;
                                                       // console.log('data_series '+data_series.data);
                                                        //
                                                      //alert(data_series.toSource());
                                                        var data_t = [] ;
                                                        var categ = [] ;
                                                        var categ_sorted = null ;
                                                        //
                                                        var graph_data = [] ;
                                                        var values = {} ;
                                                        var d = [] ;
                                                        var data_source = null ;
                                                        for(var item in data_series)
                                                        {
                                                             //  alert(data_series[item].line) ;
                                                               values['name'] = data_series[item].line ;
                                                               //
                                                               data_source = data_series[item].source ;
                                                              // alert(item);
                                                               //
                                                               sdata=[];
                                                                // alert(data_series[item].line) ;
                                                                 for(var i in data_series[item].data)
                                                                 {
                                                                //  alert(">>>>"+data_series[item].line+">>>>>>"+i+">>>"+data_series[item].data[i]);
                                                                    // 
                                                                     sdata.push(data_series[item].data[i]) ;
                                                                     //
                                                                     categ.push(i);
                                                                     //graph_data.push(values);

                                                                 }
                                                                // alert(">>>> sdatae >>>> "+sdata);
                                                                 values['data'] = sdata;
                                                                 graph_data.push(values);
                                                                 values={};
                                                                // alert(categ.toSource());
                                                                // alert(data_series[item].data) ;
                                                             //  values['name'] = data_series.line ;
                                                             //  values['data'] = [data_series.data[item]] ;
                                                               //
                                                              //alert(values.toSource()) ;
                                                              // graph_data.push(values);
                                                             //  categ.push(item);
                                                        }
                                                        //alert(graph_data.toSource());

                                                        categ_sorted = sortMonths(categ) ; 
                                                    //  alert(categ_sorted.toSource()) ;
                                                    //  alert(graph_data.toSource());
                                                    //  alert(categ.toSource());
                                                         //dynamically build graphs

                                                       $('#container').highcharts({
                                                            title: {
                                                                text: ''+graph_results.graph_name,
                                                                x: -20 //center
                                                            },
                                                            subtitle: {
                                                                text: 'Data Source: '+data_source,
                                                                x: -20
                                                            },
                                                            xAxis: {
                                                                categories: categ_sorted
                                                            },
                                                            yAxis: {
                                                                title: {
                                                                    text: ''+graph_results.name_y_axis
                                                                },
                                                                plotLines: [{
                                                                    value: 0,
                                                                    width: 1,
                                                                    color: '#808080'
                                                                }]
                                                            },
                                                            credits:
                                                            {
                                                                enabled: false
                                                            },
                                                            tooltip: {
                                                                valueSuffix: ''
                                                            },
                                                            legend: {
                                                                layout: 'vertical',
                                                                align: 'right',
                                                                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                                                borderWidth: 0
                                                            },
                                                            series: graph_data
                                                        });
```